# Encoding.Unicode not resolving

Tags: c#

I have a procedure that does some encrypting in some project (works ok), and I copied it to the project in now working with. But strangely, it cannot resolve Encoding.Unicode, the word Unicode is underlined with red.

The error I'm getting says:
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Unicode' and no extension method 'Unicode' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is in one of my general.cs class files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace myNamespace
{
    static class myClass
    {
        public static string myProc(string text)
        {
             //...
             byte[] toEncrypt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
             //...
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, when I copy the code to my main form, it doesn't give any errors, so it's something to do with this class?

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);`

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, that's the case, I was having private static string[] Encoding; in my declarations, totally forgot about that one!

Comment: @m.rogalski that suggestion changes the output. If they want to use the Unicode encoding (UTF-16), then using UTF-8 instead is not going to yield the results they're searching for.

Comment: @CodeCaster Unicode is not the same as UTF-16.  Unicode is character set while UTF-8/UTF-16 is encoding.

Comment: @m.rogalski in general it does, but in .NET jargon "Unicode" is equivalent to "UTF-16". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster _"In .NET jargon"_ makes no sense at all and for windows default is UTF-16LE. Read [this article](http://www.polylab.dk/utf8-vs-unicode.html).

Comment: @m.rogalski you don't have to explain the difference between character sets and encodings to me. If you want to rant at someone, rant at the .NET team who decided "Unicode" should mean "UTF-16". I don't make this up, look at the links I provided, especially the [`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) which _"Gets an encoding for the **UTF-16 format** using the little endian byte order"_. So no, the OP should not change `Encoding.Unicode` to `Encoding.UTF8`, because that means something different entirely.

Comment: @CodeCaster If not me then someone has to explain it. You wrote _"use the Unicode encoding (UTF-16)"_ which is misleading.

Comment: @m.rogalski context is important. I agree I could've written that part differently, something like _"If they want to use `Encoding.Unicode` (being UTF-16) ..."_. Thanks for explaining that that part specifically threw you off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array member named `Encoding` somewhere in scope (either in this method or in this class). Right-click the `Encoding` identifier and choose "Go To Definition..." and you'll find it.

Either rename that member, or prefix the namespace:

```
byte[] toEncrypt = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's [`UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text)`

Comment: [`System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx) does exist.